# Ember.js: How to hook model the right way?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I tried to iterate all of the roles and with `#link-to`. The problem is the first record works fine on transition but when I tried to transition to other record, checkboxes are not working and the default checked were inherited from the first record.

Template: `templates/roles.hbs`

```
<ul>
    {{#each role in controller}}
        {{#if role.name}}
            <li>
                {{#link-to 'roles.show' role}}
                    {{role.name}}
                {{/link-to}}
            </li>
        {{/if}}
    {{/each}}           
</ul>
```

Template: `templates/roles/show.hbs`

```
{{role-form role=model}}
```

This is the `component/role-form.hbs`.
I tried to `{{module.accessRights.read}}` to get the value but it only works on the first row of checkboxes and when I transition to other record, it throws an error: `TypeError: element is null`

```
{{#each module in role.modules}}
    {{module.name}}

    {{view Ember.Checkbox checkedBinding='module.accessRights.read'}}
    {{view Ember.Checkbox checkedBinding='module.accessRights.write'}}
    {{view Ember.Checkbox checkedBinding='module.accessRights.update'}}
    {{view Ember.Checkbox checkedBinding='module.accessRights.delete'}}
{{/each}}
```

Routes: `routes/roles/show.js`

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(param) {
        return this.store.find('role', param.id);
    }
});
```

Model:

```
// role.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    modules: DS.hasMany('module', {embedded: 'always'})
});

// module.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    accessRights: DS.belongsTo('access', {embedded: 'always'})
});

// access.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
    write: DS.attr('boolean'),
    read: DS.attr('boolean'),
    update: DS.attr('boolean'),
    delete: DS.attr('boolean')
});
```

Response from backend handled properly my model. Do I need to hook model on every `link-to`? I tried using `setupController` to hook model but it doesn't work.

Comment: {embedded: 'always'} doesn't actually do anything anymore, are you creating a custom serializer that takes advantage of it?

Comment: Here my custom serializer: http://pastebin.com/ADP8RtJ7

Comment: would you mind dropping the json in, or maybe it implemented in example form in emberjs.jsbin.com, I'd need to play with the deserialized content to dig deeper.  Additionally you can do the checkbox with the input helper `{{input type='checkbox' checked=foo.bar}}`

Comment: Here's JSON response from backend: http://pastebin.com/hbE8SJca
Sorry I'm still new to Ember. Thanks

Comment: The issue was from the custom serializer, on `sideloadItem` function. When `id` is already in the `sideloadArr`, it returns the payload without pushing it to `sideloadArr` and `payload` so they used the same record (id). I don't know what I'm doing. Anybody? Thanks.